# how to send http patch request in objective c

Tags: objective-c

I am developing an application which needs to send data to server which is expecting a PATCH request this request takes 2 parameters types header and path, I don't know how this works help me out of this .

Comment: Could you share some code to give us a hint what do you have already?

Comment: This question got resolved